# How to handle multiple requests at single restfull webservice end point

Tags: web-services, grails

I have developed web application using grails web framework and am developing this for my e-commerce platform where am giving offers to users like "Flash Sale".

I have successfully created the api for this in one of my controller where am booking for the product. The logic here is `If that product is completely sold and is not available i.e in other words if i have 0 products remaining then i shouldn't book the product and should tell the booking user about this, for this am returning status code as 204`.

The confusion which is bothering me here is, `What if many customers starts booking the product exactly at the same time altogether. Scenario lets say i have only 20 pieces of product to be sold and 21 customers started booking the product at the same time`. For this I shall lock/ process the api requests one by one (queuing). Am not having idea of how to do this, please help me out.

Comment: This is the type of thing that is not a great question for StackOverflow because the details can be involved.  How you handle this depends on factors in your app like what type of database you are using, who do you want to `"win"` when competing changes are requested, should any of them fail, if using JDBC then what is your transaction isolation level, etc.  This isn't a straightforward coding questions.  This is a how do I architect my application question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever used the `synchronized` keyword in Java? It is used to form a thread queue where threads will form a line to access a particular piece of code. In order to determine whether or not a thread should wait, you pass an object instance to the synchronized block and if there is already another thread using the same block on the same instance, it will wait until all previous threads are done. This article explains the use of synchronized: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/synchronized-in-java/.

Also, here is an example of what I mean. I am going to just use a static object instance, meaning that all threads will use the same object instance which will make them all wait their turn:

```
static Object threadLock = new Object();

void doSomething() {
    // region Some code that all threads can execute at once
    ...
    // endregion

    // region Synchronized code
    synchronized(threadLock) {
        // Have your winner logic here. Threads will only go into this block in a first-come-first-served basis.
    }
    // endregion
}
```

You could also mark the entire method as synchronized for simplicity, but then all logic in the method must be done in a synchronous manner when it may not be needed. Use either approach at your own discretion.